# Edit: QUESTION CHANGED - SQL: Taking all rows from table where column names are NOT in another table 

Tags: sql, oracle

Never done SQL before (how that's possible I don't know),

I have two tables, like so:

```
Table1:

Column Names:    A    B    C
Rows:            1  sdf  sdsd
                 2  seg  werr
```

and

```
Table2:

Column Names:    A    B    C     D    E    F
Rows:            1    sdf  sdsd  yuj  uui  ddd
                 1    sdf  sdsd  sss  sdd  ssw
                 1    sdf  sdsd  jut  scv  sef
                 2    seg  werr  oel  ewe  wee
                 2    seg  werr  ujf  etr  wuk
                 2    seg  werr  los  hjd  wee
```

EDIT: Question changed.

How do I take all rows with the columns that are unique in the 2nd table? I.e. I only want the data from D, E and F where the values in A, B, C in Table1 correspond to the A, B, C values in Table2.

So for instance given A=1 and B=sdf, I want the rows:

```
sdsd  yuj  uui  ddd
sdsd  sss  sdd  ssw
sdsd  jut  scv  sef
```

I could just go: SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE A='1' AND B='sdf' but I would get

```
1    sdf  sdsd  yuj  uui  ddd
1    sdf  sdsd  sss  sdd  ssw
1    sdf  sdsd  jut  scv  sef
```

Comment: It isn't :P My bad, fixed now.

Comment: In addition to Charles' question: What DBMS? The answer may vary between them (if there is one).

Comment: What flavor of SQL? (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.)

Comment: Oracle, but i'd prefer agnostic if possible.

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT C, D, E, F FROM Table2 WHERE A='1' AND B='sdf'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just list columns you want to select.

So for instance given `A='1'` and `B='sdf'` :

```
SELECT C,D,E,F FROM Table2 WHERE A='1' AND B='sdf'
```

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way would be:

```
Select D, E From Table2
```

If you are looking for something dynamic, the solution will depend on which database vendor you are using. There is not an agnostic dynamic solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `LEFT JOIN` (or `RIGHT JOIN`) with a special operation in the `WHERE` to look for non-matching values.

In this case, something like this:

```
SELECT Table2.*
FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 USING (SomeCommonField)
WHERE Table1.SomeCommonField IS NULL
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he is looking for.

Comment: Mmm. It is hard to tell. I made an assumption the OP was fuddling some concepts. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, You need to access the system tables or the catalog views to do this.  The exact syntax would depend on what DBMS you are using...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that here you have one of the only cases where a NATURAL JOIN is the proper solution since your column names are exactly the same in both tables.

```
 SELECT D, E, F
   FROM table1
NATURAL JOIN table2
  WHERE a = '1'
    AND b = 'sdf'
    AND c = 'sdsd'
```